# Drools rule to check for empty conditions in Collection for versions above 5.4.0

Tags: drools, rule

Previously in Drools 5.1.1 version there was a privilege to check for empty conditions.

For example if a variable of type Collection has no values in it and we want to write a condition for this check, we used to write like

```
variable.empty == true
```

This was a valid rule for Drools 5.1.1. But now when I try to do the same in version 5.4.0, it is not supported. I tried to search for some alternative but could not find one.

Can someone help with this.

Answer (score 2):

With `List<String> authors` in Book and the appropriate getter, this rule works fine in 5.4.0 and 5.5.0:

```
rule noAuthors
when
    $b1: Book( authors.empty == true )
then
    System.out.println( "No authors: " + $b1.getTitle() );
end
```

There may be some other snag in your code. What makes you say "not supported"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just accessing the properties of your collection? i.e.

```
Collection( size == 0 )
```

... will match any `Collection` which is empty.